# If my model inherits from res.partner will its data be visible in modules that use res.partner, such as CRM

Tags: odoo

I have a custom model `mymodule.contacts` which inherits from `res.partner` because I new a few extra fields. I would like my records that I add to `mymodule.contacts` to be visible in the other Odoo modules, **sans** my extra fields .. i.e. the fields in my model which inherit from `res.partner` are the only ones that possibly could be visible in the other Odoo models and that's fine. so for example, the Invoice module uses the `res.partner` model. My model inherits from res.partner. However since Odoo should create my model as a new table in Postgres, I dont think any of my contact data in my custom model will be visible to the Invoices module, despite inheriting from res.partner, because the actual data is in a different Postgres table. Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the kind of inheritance you're doing. If you do a simple inheritance with

`_inherit = res.partner`

To add new fields to the `res.partner` model, then Yes the new fields would be available to any model that has links to `res.partner`

On the other hand if you do a polymorphic inheritance with

`_inherits = res.partner`

Or you specify a `_name` while inheriting, A new table would be created in postgres with the attributes of the old model and your new fields won't be available to other models that inherit `res.partner`.

I think what you're really looking for is `_inherits`, it creates a new table for you. The default data for `res.partner` would still be stored in it's table but the new data would be stored in the new table you specified, so other models would never get to know of the new fields you added.

There is a great visualization here on the types of inheritance in Odoo.

https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/whats-the-difference-between-inherit-and-inherits-52205

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit a model, you simply gain its characteristics so that you can build on it. The inherited model or any other model will not have any visibility to your model unless its connected. The extra fields you add to your extension model will not be visible to any other model unless you connect them with many2one ,one2many or many2many fields.